# The item of an unregistered user's cart is shown a different unregistered user

Tags: commerce

Using Drupal Commerce 2 in Drupal 8.8, if an unregistered user puts something in the cart (and doesn't check it out) another unregistered user sees these items in *Cart* block (provided by view (order)). They aren't shown to the users on the /cart page.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the behavior described above is that in Views I changed the advanced option context filter - order id - for "if there is no value for the context filter" from: "static" (the option after installation, which had the effect that no cart was shown at all) to "show all results" (with the effect described above).

I found this link https://www.drupal4u.org/howtos/how-hide-empty-shopping-cart-drupal-commerce saying the correct value would be "Current user's cart order ID", but this was not available. I'm not sure if this is a bug, if things changed for Commerce 2 or if I configured something wrong.

Comment: Maybe file an issue for further investigation.

Comment: I tried a new question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/294319/cart-block-doesnt-show-any-content

Answer (score 0):

Without know your specific site, it's hard to say what the culprit is, but this sounds like a pretty typical caching issue. Ultimately, you need to prevent Drupal from caching pages or page elements rendered for anonymous users with shopping carts.

Comment: When I use the button "clear all caches" the problem remains. Is this an indication that it is not a cache issue or is this a matter of a different level of cache?

Comment: Even if you clear the cache, as soon as someone visits the page again, it will be re-cached with whatever their cart contents are and then visible for all to see. I'm not versed enough in all the options for cache invalidation, so I'll see if someone else can chime in - but you basically need to get to a point where this element isn't being cached at all.

Comment: If somebody had any idea how to prevent this element from being cached, I would really appreciate it. My first step war to configure order types that an abandoned cart will be cleared after two hours to mitigate the problem.

Comment: I deinstalled the core module Internal Dynamic Page Cache the only cache module that was installed, but it didn't change the site's behaviour.