# Cart block doesn't show any content

Tags: views, 8, commerce

After installing, the cart block view doesn't show any content, even when I had put something in the cart.

I found [How to hide an empty shopping cart with drupal commerce](https://www.drupal4u.org/howtos/how-hide-empty-shopping-cart-drupal-commerce), which  says the correct value would be *Current user's cart order ID*, but this is not available in my installation.

I'm not sure if this is a bug, things changed for Drupal Commerce 2, or I configured something wrong.

I'm using Drupal 8.9.0 and Drupal Commerce 2.1.9.

Comment: Does the issue persist if you switch to the Bartik, default, theme? OR if you strip all CSS with a browser tool, can you see the cart?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I think the link you have found is about Commerce 1.x (https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce1/user-guide/shopping-cart/modifying-the-shopping-cart-using-views). I'm using Commerce 2.x and have the same problem, "Current user's cart order ID" is missing

Comment: Yes, it's independent of the theme, I tried this. And the link is about Commerce 1.x. But I didn't find anything about Commerce 2.